# Class 'PayPal\Common\PayPalModel' not found Angell EYE Paypal SDK Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Does anyone know that why I got this error :

> Class 'PayPal\Common\PayPalModel' not found

It seems that the library SDK PayPal from Angel EYE didn't come with the folder and file above.

I got this error when trying to run the Rest **CreateSinglePayout** to send money to another account.

Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i solve the problem,

That because i copy the library without installing using composer.

To make it work, try installing using composer. It should work.

Comment: How's that? The folder doesn't exist even on the GitHub repository :/